# Lombok with maven at Openshift (Jboss AS) build fails

Tags: maven, java-7, openshift, lombok

I started using Lombok in my project and all is working well in my local environment (maven compile is working). When I try to pusth to openshift (Jboss installation) maven compile in openshift fails with errors:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ german-school ---
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files to /var/lib/openshift/5290ebf4500446c6e20000b8/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/5290ebf4500446c6e20000b8/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/gr/alx/german/model/Word.java:[95,26] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class Word /var/lib/openshift/5290ebf4500446c6e20000b8/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/gr/alx/german/model/Word.java:[102,18] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable shuffledWord of type Word /var/lib/openshift/5290ebf4500446c6e20000b8/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/gr/alx/german/model/Word.java:[114,19] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable shuffledWord of type Word /var/lib/openshift/5290ebf4500446c6e20000b8/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/gr/alx/german/controller/AdminController.java:[70,18] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class Word
...
...
...
...
[INFO] 33 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

I am not showing every error for clarity. The class 'Word' is a class annotated with Lombok annotations. Maven seems to be unable to find the class at all.

I should note that I am using java 7.

Comment: Can you tell what lombok annotations are in Word.java? Or maybe even the smallest possible file that reproduces or demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Annotations in Word are: Data, NoArgsConsctuctor, Builder. Again, locally everything works correctly

Comment: tried also with just @ Data same errors

Comment: I've been using Lombok annotations on OpenShift for months, no problem so far. Can you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Could you parse the <build> part of your maven project

Comment: @alex you resolve this problem? I have the same Issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. It was something to do with an older version of the maven compile plugin.

To fix it change your plugins version to specifically **request maven compile 2.5.1 (or higher)**

here's the important part of my maven pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
     <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when invoking mvn. -->
     <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app will need. -->
     <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' folder. -->
     <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
     <id>openshift</id>
     <build>
        <finalName>myname</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                      <warName>ROOT</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

NOTE: 
maven-compiler-plugin - version 2.5.1